# Splitting a string into individual words (java)

Tags: java

So I am trying to split a sentence into individual words and the code I am using is not working. I keep getting a null answer. After I break the sentence into words, I want to send each individual word to be converted to pig latin and then added to a string to form the original sentence but in pig latin.

Here is the code I have:

```
public class PigLatin
{
    String input;
    String pLatin = "";

    public PigLatin()
    {
       this.input = "Cool";
       this.pLatin = "Oolcay";
    }

    public PigLatin (String input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void breakInput(String input)
    {
        String[] words = input.split("\\s");
        for(int i=0; i < words.length; i++)
        {  
            System.out.println(words[i]);
            changeWord(words[i]);
        }
    }

    public void changeWord(String w)
    {
        char ch = w.charAt(0);
        String letter = ch+"";
        String beg = w.substring(1,w.length());
        String end = letter.concat("ay");
        String word = beg.concat(end);

        this.pLatin = pLatin.concat(" " + word);
        System.out.println(this.pLatin);
     }

    public String toString()
    {
        String ans = this.input + "\n" + this.pLatin;
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], and read [ask].

Comment: Specifically, you may want to print the actual output of this program, rather than just saying "I keep getting a null answer".

Comment: I can run your code, and I see the output just fine.  Be more specific about how you're running your code, what output you're seeing and what output you're expecting.